# implementing algorithms in databases

Tags: database, computer-science

I am new to databases, was eager to know how algorithms and data structures are implemented in databases.

like how will I implement BFS or a red-black tree in database.

would be thankful if you can explain me that or provide a link,

Comment: This is way too broad for Stack Overflow I'm afraid. Have you Googled? A query e.g. for `how to implement bfs in database` is sure to turn up useful info.

Comment: yeah..some link or tutorial will help :)